# Items moved to trash still show in site navigation

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am logged in as Admin. In 'Reorganize Pages', moving pages from the main navigation schema to the Trash, the item(s) still show in the main navigation on the site. In other words, moving items to the Trash has no effect. Image attached showing a page titled "Introduction" in the Trash folder. That page still shows up on the live site even after committing the change.[image]

Comment: Are you using apostrophe-workflow? Or is your nav built manually with a widget rather than using the page tree directly? Those might be two simple cases where this might happen. Could you include a stripped-down version of your nav template code?

Comment: Yes, using apostrophe-workflow. Code is on JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bmauger/gpkarudq/

Comment: My guess is that you need to commit the changes to those pages (via the Workflow menu item at the top) to have the changes take effect in the nav.

Comment: I have been committing the changes via the main menu but not the Workflow menu. Committing (also) from the Workflow menu seems to have done the trick. Thank you @alexbea!

Comment: Great! I added that as an answer so it's clearer for other people as well. Please check that out and accept if it looks good to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using apostrophe-workflow, it's most likely that you need to commit the changes to those pages for the changes to take effect in the nav (in Live mode, at least). Check out the "Workflow" menu item (at the top of the page) to do this.